# Why is the parking brake called hand brake

Tags: brakes, parking

Why is the parking brake called hand brake? Mechanics?

From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia:
The most common use for a parking brake is to keep a vehicle motionless when it is parked.

Comment: ... because it is used by hand, rather than by foot? (I don't think I've heard the foot-activated kind called a "hand brake"...)

Comment: in what way does the wikipedia article fail to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

It’s only recently that parking brakes are electronic... most have been hand-operated with a few that were foot operated. Mercedes had foot operated parking brakes for some models.

Comment: A lot of American manufactured vehicles still have foot operated parking brakes. GM is quite fond of them.

Comment: No one says you can't still use your hand on a foot pedal...  :p